# Uploading Image to server using direct link and without form in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, hyperlink, sftp

This code allow me to choose an Image and upload it:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="image" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

I want to upload the image using a direct link to the target image and without using a form or file selector.. 
so the image could be uploaded as soon as loading the php file

Comment: could you please specify further what you mean by "using a direct link"?

Comment: means you will have a link of an image from remote server. and you are going to upload that into your server? is it so?

Comment: I want to upload an Image as soon as loadinf the php file, without selecting image from the computer @FranzGleichmann

Comment: @Hussein so you want at website, that without any user interaction, accesses a local file of the users computer? that'd be hopefully impossible, because it would be a fundamental security flaw.